# Attaching a blob to a form using FormData append not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a blob with a file and want to attach it to a form.

This is my code:

```
var blob = getBlob(); //has the blob
var form = document.querySelector('.my-form');
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('imageFile', blob);
```

Then when I submit the form to a `send.php` file, I try this:

```
echo $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'];
```

and get nothing. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's because you have a parse error; as in `unexpected T_ECHO`.

Comment: Either echo $file after setting it or remove the $file = part

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner tried removing the "$file =" part and still can't see anything

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner also, if I add a <input type="file"> and upload the file manually, I do see the tmp_name

Comment: Adding a file to a FormData object does not add it to the form

Comment: @Musa then what does it do? And how do I add it to the form?

Comment: Upload the file via ajax...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @Musa oh I get it now, I need to append the blob right before sending the form via ajax, the use the formdata as the data property?

Comment: @Akintunde007 wut?